# Intersection of compact set in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space.
>    Prove that if $\{ C_i | i \in I \}$ is an infinite collection of compact subsets of $X$ such that $\cap_{i \in I} C_i = \emptyset$, then some finite sub collection of $\{ C_i | i \in I \}$ also has an empty intersection.

Well my idea is that I want to show that $X$ is compact. Since each $C_i$ is a compact subset of $X$, this means each $C_i$ is closed, which means $(X \setminus C_i)$ is an open set. I want to say that $\cup_{i \in I} (X \setminus C_i)$ is an open cover of X but I don't know if this proves $X$ is a compact set. Do you think I am on the right track? Thank you very much.

Comment: compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed, not true in general. what is the topology on X?

Comment: I have edited the title. Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: see, if you have written "Since each $Ci$ is a compact subset of $X$, this means each $Ci$ is closed''. This is not true in general unless your space is Hausdorff.

Comment: if $X$ is compact then your statement is true (because X has finite intersection property). But the converse may not be true(which you are trying to prove).

Comment: But I am assuming that X is Hausdorff. Could I still say that?

Comment: you can take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and$C_i=[i, i+1]$. But R is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ need not be compact but the implication is true as long as $X$ is Hausdorff.

Fix $j \in I$. Then $C_j$ is covered by $X \setminus C_i, i \neq j$. Hence there is a finite subcover, say $C_{i_1},C_{i_2}...,C_{i_n}$. Now the intersection of   $C_j,C_{i_1},C_{i_2}...,C_{i_n}$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The result holds even when $X$ is not itself compact, so you’ll have trouble proving that $X$ is compact (because it doesn’t *have* to be...) But you are on *almost* the right track. The trick is to stick the intersection into a compact set.

Pick $i_0\in I$. If $C_{i_0}$ is empty, then you are done: just take $\{i_0\}$. Otherwise, for each $i\in I$ define $D_i=C_i\cap C_{i_0}$. Note that because $X$ is Hausdorff, each $C_i$ is closed; hence $D_i$ is closed for each $i$, and all contained in $C_{i_0}$.

Since $D_i\subseteq C_i$ for each $i$, the intersection of all $D_i$ is empty. Since $C_{i_0}$ is compact...